# Garbage Collection with temporary instances of classes

Tags: java, android, sqlite, memory-leaks

I am relatively new to android development and being from a c# background it is entirely possible my entire strategy is wrong, but I am continually getting warned by Eclipse when degugging that I haven't closed a database connection properly causing a memory leak.

I have a base database class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        this(context, "myDb", null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE MyTable (A INT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Cursor executeSelect(String sql, String[] parameters) {
        return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, parameters);
    }

}
```

---

A generic entity:

---

```
public class MyClass {
    private int a;

    public void setA(int value) {
        this.a = value;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
}
```

---

And essentially a service for `MyClass` (although in reality this extends a generic abstract class for reusability purposes)

---

```
public class MyClassService {

    private MySQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    private Context context;

    public MyClassService(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private MySQLiteOpenHelper getHelper() {
        if (helper == null) {
            helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this.context);
        }
        return helper;
    }

    public void dispose() {
        if (helper != null) {
            helper.close();
            helper = null;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<MyClass> getAll()
    {
        ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
        Cursor cursor = getHelper().executeSelect("SELECT A FROM MyTable", new String[0]);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            MyClass item = new MyClass()
            item.setA(cursor.getInt(0));
            list.add(item);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

So, my question is when I use a line of code like this from an Activity:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new MyClassService(this).getAll();
```

is the instance of `MyClassService` disposed of immediately, or could this be the source of my memory leaks.

Would I be better calling the full code to ensure the database is closed using the dispose method?

```
MyClassService svc = new MyClassService(this);
ArrayList<MyClass> list = svc.getAll();
svc.dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Garbage Collector* would be able to collect your class, as well as the `Helper` class, since these are no longer part of the *Object chain* (not a technical term - just something I made up). However, you would still need to explicitly close the database (if you don't this would definitely be your memory leak culprit). As it stands, you can do this in your Object's `finalize()` method, which is called during garbage collection:

```
@Override
public void finalize() {
    dispose();
}
```

I usually prefer, however, to do things a little differently. Data Stores like this are often best written as *Singletons*, since they may be accessed by multiple classes, and if different instances are created they will still open a new access point for reading a writing, and could cause many issues. You sort of have a singleton-style setup in that there is one `helper` variable in your code, but you may want to simply make your `Helper` class the singleton. You can do this by removing your constructors and adding this:

```
private static MySQLiteOpenHelper self;

private MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

private MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    this(context, "myDb", null, 1);
}

public static MySQLiteOpenHelper sharedHelper(Context context) {
    if (self == null)
        self = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    return self;
}
```

Then, instead of keeping track of a helper object in `MyClassService` using `getHelper()`, you can get THE helper using:

```
MySQLiteOpenHelper.sharedHelper(context);
```

The benefit of doing this means you only have to keep track of one Helper throughout the entire app, and in the helper's `finalize()` method, you can now close the database. This will be called when the app process is killed, and prevent any memory leaks:

```
public void finalize()
{
    close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've both answered my question and suggested an improvement. Is there any advantage to initializing `MySQLiteOpenHelper` with `context.getApplicationContext()` rather than just `context` (passed from an activity using `this`)?

Comment: @GarethD, glad I could help! In the Android documentation, it states that passing around `Activity` context may cause memory leaks - this would occur if an activity were closed, but the helper kept a pointer to its context. The `Application` context, on the other hand is tied to the application, which if killed will also garbage collect your helper class. That said, I have never had any problems passing regular context - but it would be safest to use `Application` context (the main difference is that you can't modify the UI using application context).

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly call `dispose` - not doing so won't cause a memory leak (the object can be collected immediately after `new MyClassService(this).getAll()` because there aren't any live references to the object), but may cause your database to run out of available connections.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `close` on the database object returned from `getReadableDatabase()`.